# recursive php function: trouble spotting the bug

Tags: php, recursion

I have a family tree app in laravel, and I want to be able to show an outline view (start with a family from long ago, show its kids, show those kids' families, those families' kids, etc).

So I made this recursive get_descendants function:

```
public static function get_descendants(Family $family, $results_array, $counter)
        {
            // start new round with a different temp array, to keep track
            $counter++;
            $this_array = "array_$counter";
            $$this_array = [];

            array_push ($$this_array, $family->caption);

            $kids = FamilyController::get_kids_of_family($family);

            // if family has no kids, return 0;
            if (!count($kids))
            {
                return 0;
            }

            else // add kids and check for their families
            {
                foreach ($kids as $kid) {
                    array_push ($$this_array, $kid->firstname);

                    // get families made by kid- for each one, call get_descendants
                    $families_made = FamilyController::get_families_person_made($kid);

                    foreach ($families_made as $new_family) {
                        array_push($$this_array, self::get_descendants($new_family, $$this_array, $counter));
                    }
                };

                // we've gone through the kids, add this round's array to the general results array
                array_push ($results_array, $$this_array);
            }
            return $results_array; 
        }
```

I've confirmed with print statements that the looping through is correct, but there's a problem with the way I'm saving the results.  I want to get something like this, where the top family shows once, with children and their families nested:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    0 => "Padme & Anakin"
    1 => "Leia"
    2 => array:3 [▼
      0 => "Leia & Han"
      1 => "Kylo Ren"
    ]
    3 => "Luke"
  ]
]
```

but I'm getting this (with an extra repeat in the middle):

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    0 => "Padme & Anakin"
    1 => "Leia"
    2 => array:3 [▼
      0 => "Padme & Anakin"
      1 => "Leia"
      2 => array:3 [▼
        0 => "Leia & Han"
        1 => "Kylo Ren"
      ]
    ]
    3 => "Luke"
  ]
]
```

**Can anyone see where my mistake is?**

Comment: Thanks Ryan- yes good idea on giving a way to test it!  Everything's in a database right now... I'm not sure what you mean about making a PHP source array, but if you know of a tutorial page I'm happy to do it.

Comment: Annnnd I just found the problem: everything's great if I just return the $$this_array and leave out the general $results_array.  I see now that 'find the bug' post is a terrible idea without an easier way for people to dig in- sorry for the confusion or wasted time

Comment: Glad you fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

Update: it turns out that it works if I get rid of that final results_array and just use the dynamic one the whole way, like this:

```
    public static function get_descendants(Family $family, $results_array, $counter)
    {
        // start new round with a different temp array, to keep track
        $counter++;
        $this_array = "array_$counter";
        $$this_array = [];

        array_push ($$this_array, $family->caption);

        $kids = FamilyController::get_kids_of_family($family);

        // if family has no kids, return 0;
        if (!count($kids))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        else // add kids and check for their families
        {
            foreach ($kids as $kid) {
                array_push ($$this_array, $kid->first);

                // get families made by kid- for each one, call get_descendants
                $families_made = FamilyController::get_families_person_made($kid);

                if (count($families_made))
                {
                    foreach ($families_made as $new_family) {

                        array_push($$this_array, self::get_descendants($new_family, $$this_array, $counter));
                    }
                }

            };

        }
        return $$this_array;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks unnecessarily complex, with dynamic arrays, and you keep populating the same array, so that's why Luke appears in the wrong place.

A cleaner solution might be to be very specific about where people are in the array rather than using a dynamic array name. Just a suggestion -

```
public static function getDescendants(Family $family)
{
    $family = [];
    $family['name'] = $family->caption;
    if ($kids = static::getKidsOfFamily($family)) {
        foreach ($kids as $kid) {
            $family['children'][] = $kid->firstname;
            $subfamilies = static::getFamiliesPersonMade($kid);
            foreach ($subfamilies as $subfamily) {
                $family['subfamilies'][] = static::getDescendants($subfamily);
            }
        };
    }

    return $family; 
}
```

would produce something like

```
array [
    "name" => "Padme & Anakin"
    "children" => array [
        "Leia",
        "Luke"
    ],
    "subfamilies" => array [
        array [
            "name" => "Leia & Han"
            "children" => array [
                "Kylo Re"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: thanks, @gingerCodeNinja!  I'm thinking about how that could work.... the part that makes my brain explode is that my family tree goes 7 generations back, so I need a way within "subfamilies" to be able to keep going deeper and deeper- I'm not quite clear on how I'd be able to connect them within "subfamilies".... could you say more?  PS- I made one simplification in the code above, which brings my result into one array, just with extra cruft in the middle